# How to assign a column value based on number of rows in that group

Tags: python, pandas, loops

Create some test data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ID = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000000,size=(100, 1)), columns=['ID'])
Prob = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100,size=(100, 1)), columns=['Probability'])/100


cuts = [{'flag': 'L', 'cut': 44},
         {'flag': 'M', 'cut': 31},
         {'flag': 'H', 'cut': 25}]

cuts = pd.DataFrame(cuts)

df = pd.concat([ID.reset_index(drop=True), Prob], axis=1)
df = df.sort_values(by=['Probability'])
df["flag"] = np.nan
```

I have two datasets I am working with, one is a list of probabilities from a predictive model, the other is a list of cut points calculated based on the length of the list it's given. I would like to find an efficient way to assign these values to the 'flag' column of df.

For this example, the first 44 rows would be assigned 'L', the next 31 rows will be assigned 'M' and the last 25 rows will be assigned 'H'

My environment is with many more different flag values and millions of rows but for simplicity I am using 100 rows and 3 flags in the example.

How do I assign these flags using 'the next x number of rows' and not the index or some other reference key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `repeat`:

```
df['flag'] = cuts['flag'].repeat(cuts['cut']).values
```

Output:

```
        ID  Probability flag
1   803927         0.02    L
50  356764         0.03    L
52  132415         0.03    L
28  699693         0.03    L
20  296581         0.03    L
.
.
.
76  236620         0.97    H
70   56385         0.99    H
92  205281         0.99    H
75  804810         0.99    H
29  773553         0.99    H
```

Comment: Thanks, that was much simpler than I thought it would be.